# Importing Apache Lucene-Solr into Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, solr, lucene, ivy

I'm having a great deal of difficulty importing the source from `git://git.apache.org/lucene-solr.git` into Eclipse. I mean, I can import it as a vanilla non-java project, but that's not very helpful. It's not a Maven project, but it has this Ivy thing. I've download the IvyDE plugin, but I don't understand how to use it to import a project, and I haven't found any useful documentation from the Lucene project relevant to my problem.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

To be clear, I'm not trying to add Lucene to any application. I simply want to browse the source code in Eclipse as a stand-alone project.

Comment: In the meantime, I've just added lucene-core, lucene-demo, etc. as dependencies of a test Maven project.

Answer (score 5):

I did just

```
ant compile
ant eclipse
```

and then in Eclipse

> File -> Import -> Existing Projects Into workspace

and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the needed steps here [1]. As you said, it's not a maven project so there are some preliminary (ant) steps to do before.

---

[1] https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute#Getting_the_source_code

Answer (score 0):

Although Lucene is not --- at first ---  a maven project, you can create a Maven project with a provided Ant target (I guess it is a target but I haven't checked the code).

In the sub-directory dev-tools/maven/README.maven there are instructions on how to make Lucene a Maven project:

```
ant get-maven-poms 
cd maven-build
```

Now you can use all the normal Maven commands and import the Maven project into Eclipse (although it won't show the source).

If you wish to edit the source use:

```
ant compile
ant eclipse
```

Happy coding!

Ref.:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_0/dev-tools/maven/README.maven

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_0/README.txt